# Get the previous visible element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul>` like

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li style="display:none;">4</li>
<li class="curSelected">5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Now from `<li>` 5 I want the reference of the previous visible element i.e `<li>` 3

How can I get it?

I tried `$('li.curSelected').prev(":visible:last");`

But this is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.prevUntil()` to search up to (but not including) the first visible item, then use `.prev()`:

```
$('.curSelected').prevUntil(':visible').prev()
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, this wouldn't work if the immediately previous item is already visible. Unfortunately, there's no optimal jQuery for that, so here's an alternative:

```
$prev = $('.curSelected')
do {
    $prev = $prev.prev();
} while ($prev.length && $prev.is(':hidden'));
```

Comment: Yes, I supposed that if you do prevUntil and it finds the nearest element it will return the current element, it surprised me it doesn't. It looks out of the logic of the function to return an empty object in that case. I ended up using the prevAll solution above.

Comment: @RonenFestinger That's fine. Do note that `prevAll()` traverses *all* siblings before giving you the result, not just until it hits the one you want.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('li.curSelected').prevAll(":visible:first");
```

`prev()` returns only the immediate element preceding the selected one. [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) returns all previous.

Comment: This will select `<li>1</li>`!

Comment: The above comment by @NiccolòCampolungo is incorrect. This solution seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

Since jQuery traverses the dom, using [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), from the current to the first, but returns only one element(the previous), you should use [`.prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

```
$("li.curSelected").prevAll(":visible:first");
```

See a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w43hQ/) of this example.

Comment: @Veeru A S this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example. Works perfect, any browser.

```
var elem = $( some_thing ).next();
while( elem && elem[0] != undefined && !elem.is( ':visible' ) )
    elem = elem.next();
if( elem && elem[0] != undefined )
    elem.doSomething();
```

Comment: next or prev - doesn't matter